# Problems with .htaccess redirecting between folders / filename change

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have uploaded a new website to a GoDaddy Shared Linux hosting account. The previous site used this structure:

```
Root
----/about (folder)
----/maintenance (folder)
----/services (folder)
...
```

Each of these folders had an index.html file.

The new site structure is different:

```
Root
.htaccess
about.htm (file in root)
maintenance.htm (file in root)
services.htm (file in root)
...
```

I uploaded this .htaccess file to redirect any calls made to old URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.com
RewriteRule (.*) http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
rewriterule ^services\/index\.html "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/services\.htm" [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
rewriterule ^why_wood\/index\.html "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/why-wood\.htm" [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
rewriterule ^about\/index\.html "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/about\.htm" [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
rewriterule ^what-to-expect\/index\.html "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/faq\.htm" [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
rewriterule ^maintenance\/index\.html "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/maintenance\.htm" [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
rewriterule ^contact\/index\.html "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/contact\.htm" [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$
rewriterule ^index\.html "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/index\.htm" [R=301,L]
```

Using a Server Header Checker Tool located at [stepforth](http://www.stepforth.com/resources/server-header-checker-tool), I checked if the redirects were working. Here is what came back:

```
**Input**
domainname.com/about/index.html
**Output**
www.domainname.com/about.htm/index.html (**expected** www.domainname.com/about.htm)
```

The first redirect (non-www to www) works fine.

The last redirect (root index.html to root index.htm) works fine.

All the rest result in a 404 error. :-(

I have looked all over for 3 hours but have not found any information that even hinted at what to change in the rewrites. There are only 7 old URLs but it is the first of 2 problems that need fixing before I can call it complete.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a one line rewrite that works better than I expected.

The author's example was for redirecting URLs for non-existent favicon requests back to a single existing favicon in the root of the site. The article is on [Perishable Press](http://perishablepress.com/redirect-all-requests-for-a-nonexistent-file-to-the-actual-file/).

Hope this helps someone.